# pgfplot bar graph legend and y labeling

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, legend

I would like to ask how to get my results.

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
legend style={cells={anchor=west},at={(1.75,0.89)}}, area legend,
    %legend style={at={(1,-1)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,legend cell align=left},
        x tick label style={ /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Revenue (\$\,billions),
    enlargelimits=0.05,width=10cm,height=12cm,
    bar width=12pt,
]
    \addplot coordinates
        {(2012,1388) (2013,1388) (2014,1388) (2015,1388) (2016,1388) (2017,1388) (2018,1500)};
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{InkJet Head}} 

    \addplot coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   2995    ) ( 2013    ,   3144.75 ) ( 2014    ,   3294.5  ) ( 2015    ,   2126.45 ) ( 2016    ,   3594    ) ( 2017    ,   3893.5  ) ( 2018    ,   4342.75 ) }; 
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Pressure sensors}} 

    \addplot  coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   3594    ) ( 2013    ,   3923.45 ) ( 2014    ,   4193    ) ( 2015    ,   4432.6  ) ( 2016    ,   4792    ) ( 2017    ,   5091.5  ) ( 2018    ,   5450.9  ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microphones}} 

    \addplot [color=yellow, fill=yellow] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   5361.05 ) ( 2013    ,   5450.9  ) ( 2014    ,   5690.5  ) ( 2015    ,   5960.05 ) ( 2016    ,   6289.5  ) ( 2017    ,   6529.1  ) ( 2018    ,   6738.75 )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Accelerometers}} 

    \addplot [color=black, fill=white] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   6648.9  ) ( 2013    ,   6888.5  )  (    2014    ,   7128.1  ) ( 2015    ,   7188    ) ( 2016    ,   7457.55 ) ( 2017    ,   7637.25 ) ( 2018    ,   7787    )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Gyroscopes}} 

    \addplot [color=violet, fill=violet] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   6948.4  ) ( 2013    ,   7337.75 )  (    2014    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2015    ,   7727.1  ) ( 2016    ,   7787    )  (    2017    ,   8086.5  ) ( 2018    ,   8236.25 )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Digital compass}} 

    \addplot [color=gray, fill=gray] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7337.75 ) ( 2013    ,   7906.8  ) ( 2014    ,   8445.9  )  (    2015    ,   9164.7  ) ( 2016    ,   9584) ( 2017    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2018    ,   10482.5 ) };        
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Inertial combos}} 

    \addplot [color=purple, fill=purple] coordinates
        {(2012,7487.5) (2013,8176.35) (2014,8835.25) (2015,9494.15) (2016,10033.25) (2017,10632.25) (2018,11021.6)};        
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microbolometers}} 


\addplot [color=pink, fill=pink] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2013    ,   8236.25 ) ( 2014    ,   8850.225    ) ( 2015    ,   9509.125    ) ( 2016    ,   10048.225   ) ( 2017    ,   10647.225   ) ( 2018    ,   11081.5 ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{PIR \& thermopiles}} 


\addplot [color=olive, fill=olive] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7562.375    ) ( 2013    ,   8251.225    ) ( 2014    ,   8865.2  ) ( 2015    ,   9524.1  ) ( 2016    ,   10063.2 ) ( 2017    ,   10662.2 ) ( 2018    ,   11096.475   ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Micro displays}} 


\addplot [color=magenta, fill=magenta] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8386    ) ( 2013    ,   9134.75 ) ( 2014    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2015    ,   10886.825   ) ( 2016    ,   11740.4 ) ( 2017    ,   12608.95    ) ( 2018    ,   13477.5 ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Projection systems}}


\addplot [color=lime, fill=lime] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8685.5  ) ( 2013    ,   9434.25 ) ( 2014    ,   10332.75    )  (    2015    ,   11081.5 ) ( 2016    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2017    ,   12938.4 ) ( 2018    ,   13926.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Other optical MEMS}}


\addplot [color=green, fill=green] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8985    ) ( 2013    ,   10003.3 ) ( 2014    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2015    ,   12219.6 ) ( 2016    ,   13417.6 ) ( 2017    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2018    ,   16472.5 ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for research}} 


\addplot [color=cyan, fill=cyan] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   9823.6  ) ( 2013    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2014    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2015    ,   13537.4 ) ( 2016    ,   15124.75    ) ( 2017    ,   16831.9 ) ( 2018    ,   19018.25    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for IVD}}


\addplot [color=brown, fill=brown] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10123.1 ) ( 2013    ,   11231.25    ) ( 2014    ,   12579   ) ( 2015    ,   14076.5 ) ( 2016    ,   15723.75    )  (    2017    ,   17520.75    ) ( 2018    ,   18419.25    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microdispensers}}


\addplot [color=red, fill=red] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10482.5 ) ( 2013    ,   11830.25    ) ( 2014    ,   13327.75    ) ( 2015    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2016    ,   16622.25    ) ( 2017    ,   18628.9 ) ( 2018    ,   21114.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{RF MEMS}}


\addplot [color=orange, fill=orange] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10542.4 ) ( 2013    ,   11860.2 ) ( 2014    ,   13447.55    ) ( 2015    ,   14975   ) ( 2016    ,   16921.75    ) ( 2017    ,   19018.25    ) ( 2018    ,   21564   ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Oscillators}}   


\addplot [color=black, fill=black] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10871.85    )  (    2013    ,   12279.5 ) ( 2014    ,   13777   ) ( 2015    ,   17071.5 ) ( 2016    ,   17371   ) ( 2017    ,   19617.25    ) ( 2018    ,   22312.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Others}}

%\legend{InkJet Head, Pressure sensors, Microphones,  Accelerometers, Gyroscopes, Digital compass, Inertial combos, Microbolometers, PIR \& thermopiles, Micro displays, Projection systems, Other optical MEMS, Microfluidics for research, Microfluidics for IVD, Microdispensers, RF MEMS, Oscillators, Others}
    \end{axis}
```

I have this:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

I have one description in legend at one row, but I want legend under graph with many descriptions in one row.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm aware this is not exactly what you wanted, however, in my opinion, this is much clearer, so I'd advise you to consider it. If you insist on the ragged variant, maybe someone else will be able to help, I'm not sure if it is possible. I think you'd have to desist from using the pgfplots `\legend` and define your new environment.

**Edit**: You can set the ytick labels to show 220000 instead of 2.2*10^5 by including this code in the axis options (not included in the final source code).

```
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled y ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={\,},
        fixed},
```

In a default configuration, the y label will overlap these numbers. It is, however, solved in newer versions of pgfplots. So include e.g.

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
```

in your preamble.

**Final code:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
    legend style={                    % this is modified
        legend cell align=left,       %
        legend columns=2,             %
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},     %
        anchor=north                  % up to here
    }, area legend,
    x tick label style={ /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Revenue (\$\,billions),
    enlargelimits=0.05,width=10cm,height=12cm,
    bar width=12pt,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates
    {(2012,1388) (2013,1388) (2014,1388) (2015,1388) (2016,1388) (2017,1388) (2018,1500)};
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{InkJet Head}} 

    \addplot coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   2995    ) ( 2013    ,   3144.75 ) ( 2014    ,   3294.5  ) ( 2015    ,   2126.45 ) ( 2016    ,   3594    ) ( 2017    ,   3893.5  ) ( 2018    ,   4342.75 ) }; 
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Pressure sensors}} 

    \addplot  coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   3594    ) ( 2013    ,   3923.45 ) ( 2014    ,   4193    ) ( 2015    ,   4432.6  ) ( 2016    ,   4792    ) ( 2017    ,   5091.5  ) ( 2018    ,   5450.9  ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microphones}} 

    \addplot [color=yellow, fill=yellow] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   5361.05 ) ( 2013    ,   5450.9  ) ( 2014    ,   5690.5  ) ( 2015    ,   5960.05 ) ( 2016    ,   6289.5  ) ( 2017    ,   6529.1  ) ( 2018    ,   6738.75 )};     
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Accelerometers}} 

    \addplot [color=black, fill=white] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   6648.9  ) ( 2013    ,   6888.5  )  (    2014    ,   7128.1  ) ( 2015    ,   7188    ) ( 2016    ,   7457.55 ) ( 2017    ,   7637.25 ) ( 2018    ,   7787    )};     
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Gyroscopes}} 

    \addplot [color=violet, fill=violet] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   6948.4  ) ( 2013    ,   7337.75 )  (    2014    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2015    ,   7727.1  ) ( 2016    ,   7787    )  (    2017    ,   8086.5  ) ( 2018    ,   8236.25 )};     
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Digital compass}} 

    \addplot [color=gray, fill=gray] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   7337.75 ) ( 2013    ,   7906.8  ) ( 2014    ,   8445.9  )  (    2015    ,   9164.7  ) ( 2016    ,   9584) ( 2017    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2018    ,   10482.5 ) };        
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Inertial combos}} 

    \addplot [color=purple, fill=purple] coordinates
    {(2012,7487.5) (2013,8176.35) (2014,8835.25) (2015,9494.15) (2016,10033.25) (2017,10632.25) (2018,11021.6)};        
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microbolometers}} 


    \addplot [color=pink, fill=pink] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2013    ,   8236.25 ) ( 2014    ,   8850.225    ) ( 2015    ,   9509.125    ) ( 2016    ,   10048.225   ) ( 2017    ,   10647.225   ) ( 2018    ,   11081.5 ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{PIR \& thermopiles}} 


    \addplot [color=olive, fill=olive] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   7562.375    ) ( 2013    ,   8251.225    ) ( 2014    ,   8865.2  ) ( 2015    ,   9524.1  ) ( 2016    ,   10063.2 ) ( 2017    ,   10662.2 ) ( 2018    ,   11096.475   ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Micro displays}} 


    \addplot [color=magenta, fill=magenta] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   8386    ) ( 2013    ,   9134.75 ) ( 2014    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2015    ,   10886.825   ) ( 2016    ,   11740.4 ) ( 2017    ,   12608.95    ) ( 2018    ,   13477.5 ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Projection systems}}


    \addplot [color=lime, fill=lime] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   8685.5  ) ( 2013    ,   9434.25 ) ( 2014    ,   10332.75    )  (    2015    ,   11081.5 ) ( 2016    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2017    ,   12938.4 ) ( 2018    ,   13926.75    ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Other optical MEMS}}


    \addplot [color=green, fill=green] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   8985    ) ( 2013    ,   10003.3 ) ( 2014    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2015    ,   12219.6 ) ( 2016    ,   13417.6 ) ( 2017    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2018    ,   16472.5 ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for research}} 


    \addplot [color=cyan, fill=cyan] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   9823.6  ) ( 2013    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2014    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2015    ,   13537.4 ) ( 2016    ,   15124.75    ) ( 2017    ,   16831.9 ) ( 2018    ,   19018.25    ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for IVD}}


    \addplot [color=brown, fill=brown] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   10123.1 ) ( 2013    ,   11231.25    ) ( 2014    ,   12579   ) ( 2015    ,   14076.5 ) ( 2016    ,   15723.75    )  (    2017    ,   17520.75    ) ( 2018    ,   18419.25    ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microdispensers}}


    \addplot [color=red, fill=red] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   10482.5 ) ( 2013    ,   11830.25    ) ( 2014    ,   13327.75    ) ( 2015    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2016    ,   16622.25    ) ( 2017    ,   18628.9 ) ( 2018    ,   21114.75    ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{RF MEMS}}


    \addplot [color=orange, fill=orange] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   10542.4 ) ( 2013    ,   11860.2 ) ( 2014    ,   13447.55    ) ( 2015    ,   14975   ) ( 2016    ,   16921.75    ) ( 2017    ,   19018.25    ) ( 2018    ,   21564   ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Oscillators}}   


    \addplot [color=black, fill=black] coordinates
    {(  2012    ,   10871.85    )  (    2013    ,   12279.5 ) ( 2014    ,   13777   ) ( 2015    ,   17071.5 ) ( 2016    ,   17371   ) ( 2017    ,   19617.25    ) ( 2018    ,   22312.75    ) };
    \addlegendentry{\textsc{Others}}

    %\legend{InkJet Head, Pressure sensors, Microphones,  Accelerometers, Gyroscopes, Digital compass, Inertial combos, Microbolometers, PIR \& thermopiles, Micro displays, Projection systems, Other optical MEMS, Microfluidics for research, Microfluidics for IVD, Microdispensers, RF MEMS, Oscillators, Others}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know, how to adjust y axis? I have 2.4 10^-4 etc. I want to have thousand format. 24 000 etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I am lost because I have values only in range from 1000 to 25000 but pgfplot set 220 000 as maximum value. I used dot as a pointer, I hope it is correct.

Comment: 220 000 is a cumulative value if I understand it correct. The bars are not "behind each other", they are stacked "one on top of another"...

Answer (score 1):

You could play a bit with the positioning of the legend, and specify the number of columns you want in the legend; for instance:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\*
\begin{axis}[
%
    ybar stacked,
    legend style={legend cell align=left,anchor=north west,,at={(0.0,-0.1)},legend columns=2}, area legend,
        x tick label style={ /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Revenue %(\$\,billions),
    enlargelimits=0.05,width=10cm,height=12cm,
    bar width=12pt,
]
    \addplot coordinates
        {(2012,1388) (2013,1388) (2014,1388) (2015,1388) (2016,1388) (2017,1388) (2018,1500)};
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{InkJet Head}} 

    \addplot coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   2995    ) ( 2013    ,   3144.75 ) ( 2014    ,   3294.5  ) ( 2015    ,   2126.45 ) ( 2016    ,   3594    ) ( 2017    ,   3893.5  ) ( 2018    ,   4342.75 ) }; 
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Pressure sensors}} 

    \addplot  coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   3594    ) ( 2013    ,   3923.45 ) ( 2014    ,   4193    ) ( 2015    ,   4432.6  ) ( 2016    ,   4792    ) ( 2017    ,   5091.5  ) ( 2018    ,   5450.9  ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microphones}} 

    \addplot [color=yellow, fill=yellow] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   5361.05 ) ( 2013    ,   5450.9  ) ( 2014    ,   5690.5  ) ( 2015    ,   5960.05 ) ( 2016    ,   6289.5  ) ( 2017    ,   6529.1  ) ( 2018    ,   6738.75 )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Accelerometers}} 

    \addplot [color=black, fill=white] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   6648.9  ) ( 2013    ,   6888.5  )  (    2014    ,   7128.1  ) ( 2015    ,   7188    ) ( 2016    ,   7457.55 ) ( 2017    ,   7637.25 ) ( 2018    ,   7787    )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Gyroscopes}} 

    \addplot [color=violet, fill=violet] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   6948.4  ) ( 2013    ,   7337.75 )  (    2014    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2015    ,   7727.1  ) ( 2016    ,   7787    )  (    2017    ,   8086.5  ) ( 2018    ,   8236.25 )};     
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Digital compass}} 

    \addplot [color=gray, fill=gray] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7337.75 ) ( 2013    ,   7906.8  ) ( 2014    ,   8445.9  )  (    2015    ,   9164.7  ) ( 2016    ,   9584) ( 2017    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2018    ,   10482.5 ) };        
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Inertial combos}} 

    \addplot [color=purple, fill=purple] coordinates
        {(2012,7487.5) (2013,8176.35) (2014,8835.25) (2015,9494.15) (2016,10033.25) (2017,10632.25) (2018,11021.6)};        
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microbolometers}} 

    \addplot [color=pink, fill=pink] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7547.4  ) ( 2013    ,   8236.25 ) ( 2014    ,   8850.225    ) ( 2015    ,   9509.125    ) ( 2016    ,   10048.225   ) ( 2017    ,   10647.225   ) ( 2018    ,   11081.5 ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{PIR \& thermopiles}} 

    \addplot [color=olive, fill=olive] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   7562.375    ) ( 2013    ,   8251.225    ) ( 2014    ,   8865.2  ) ( 2015    ,   9524.1  ) ( 2016    ,   10063.2 ) ( 2017    ,   10662.2 ) ( 2018    ,   11096.475   ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Micro displays}} 

    \addplot [color=magenta, fill=magenta] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8386    ) ( 2013    ,   9134.75 ) ( 2014    ,   10033.25    ) ( 2015    ,   10886.825   ) ( 2016    ,   11740.4 ) ( 2017    ,   12608.95    ) ( 2018    ,   13477.5 ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Projection systems}}

    \addplot [color=lime, fill=lime] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8685.5  ) ( 2013    ,   9434.25 ) ( 2014    ,   10332.75    )  (    2015    ,   11081.5 ) ( 2016    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2017    ,   12938.4 ) ( 2018    ,   13926.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Other optical MEMS}}

    \addplot [color=green, fill=green] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   8985    ) ( 2013    ,   10003.3 ) ( 2014    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2015    ,   12219.6 ) ( 2016    ,   13417.6 ) ( 2017    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2018    ,   16472.5 ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for research}} 

    \addplot [color=cyan, fill=cyan] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   9823.6  ) ( 2013    ,   10931.75    ) ( 2014    ,   12129.75    ) ( 2015    ,   13537.4 ) ( 2016    ,   15124.75    ) ( 2017    ,   16831.9 ) ( 2018    ,   19018.25    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microfluidics for IVD}}

    \addplot [color=brown, fill=brown] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10123.1 ) ( 2013    ,   11231.25    ) ( 2014    ,   12579   ) ( 2015    ,   14076.5 ) ( 2016    ,   15723.75    )  (    2017    ,   17520.75    ) ( 2018    ,   18419.25    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Microdispensers}}

    \addplot [color=red, fill=red] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10482.5 ) ( 2013    ,   11830.25    ) ( 2014    ,   13327.75    ) ( 2015    ,   14825.25    ) ( 2016    ,   16622.25    ) ( 2017    ,   18628.9 ) ( 2018    ,   21114.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{RF MEMS}}

    \addplot [color=orange, fill=orange] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10542.4 ) ( 2013    ,   11860.2 ) ( 2014    ,   13447.55    ) ( 2015    ,   14975   ) ( 2016    ,   16921.75    ) ( 2017    ,   19018.25    ) ( 2018    ,   21564   ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Oscillators}}   

    \addplot [color=black, fill=black] coordinates
        {(  2012    ,   10871.85    )  (    2013    ,   12279.5 ) ( 2014    ,   13777   ) ( 2015    ,   17071.5 ) ( 2016    ,   17371   ) ( 2017    ,   19617.25    ) ( 2018    ,   22312.75    ) };
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{Others}}

%\legend{InkJet Head, Pressure sensors, Microphones,  Accelerometers, Gyroscopes, Digital compass, Inertial combos, Microbolometers, PIR \& thermopiles, Micro displays, Projection systems, Other optical MEMS, Microfluidics for research, Microfluidics for IVD, Microdispensers, RF MEMS, Oscillators, Others}
    \end{axis}
%*/
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this does not exactly model what you're asking, since the number of entries per row is fixed...